# Topeak Explorer Tubular Rack two versions confusion

Tags: touring, rack, panniers, topeak

There are two versions of the "Topeak Explorer Tubular Frame Mounted Bicycle Rack"

'regular' (TA2026-B) and [29er](http://www.topeak.com/products/Racks/explorer_29er) (TA2042-B )

I'm not sure what would work best with my 700c hybrid bike?

The difference in dimensions(Size (L x W x H) 42 x 17 x 41.5 cm vs 34 x 14.2 x 41.5 cm)  seems a little odd as they both support the MTX QuickTrack™ System. I do plan to get an MTX trunk bag for it.

Comment: 29" and 700c rims are the same diameter (iso 622mm). Primarily, the difference in width and length is to accommodate wider MTB frame stays and tires...I'd stick with the TA2026-B.

Comment: Totally approve the above comment. Should you get TA2042-B for your 700c commuter would result in unneeded, excessive clearance between the tyre/mudguard and the rack.

Comment: @WTHarper post an answer and i will accept it, thank you both for you advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

29" and 700c rims are the same diameter (iso 622mm). Primarily, the difference in width and length is to accommodate wider MTB frame stays and tires...I'd stick with the TA2026-B.

Answer (score 1):

The standard rack goes well with the 700c road tires.  I just put one on my wife's Citizen 2 with 700c tires with no issues.  The taller rack you might run into adjustment issues to make it level.

Some advice though.  Loosely assemble the rack off the bike and start with the mounts by the seat post.  It is easier to bend it down for the lower mounts.

Here is a photo of the clearance between the rack and the tire.  Since then I have added fenders without any issues.

[image]

Comment: Yep, people often don't understand that the straps running to the seat post or brake bolt are intended to be bent to fit.

Comment: you do realise how old this question is?

Comment: The directions called for trying to bend them in place and screw them in.  Screw that.

@Dagon, I didn't bother to look since I was on the phone and it was on the first page.  However, if somebody happens across this, then they get a success story now and some tips.  My answer is more of a comment, but I don't have the rep to comment.